# Problems with latest Scala plug-in and NetBeans 6.9.1

Tags: scala, netbeans

I am trying to install the latest NetBeans scala plugin from http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/files/nb-scala/6.9v1.1.0/nb-scala-6.9v1.1.0.zip/download. I am running NetBeans 6.9.1. I get the following:

The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 2.1 (release version 2) but only 3.4.0.11.5 (of release version different from 2) was found.

The plugin Parsing API is requested in implementation version 4.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: You might want to clarify that this is not the "official" Scala plugin, but something called erlybird.

Comment: @Rafe is there an "official" Scala plugin for NetBeans? As far as I know the Erlybird thing is the only Scala plugin for NetBeans - it certainly is the thing that's mentioned in the wiki on the NetBeans website.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested - this question was answered [here](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-tools-Problem-with-NetBeans-6-9-1-Scala-plugin-td3228128.html).